java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require
I am expecting to run my tests from testng.xml using appium, android app, java, cucumber, testng, page object model. I can launch the app up to here `pom.getVisionAppLaunch(getDriver()).setupAppLaunch();'
but the below step failed
pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnNextLiveClassroom();
BASECLASS:
public class VisionBase {

    // ThreadLocal to hold the Appium driver
    private ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    // Method to set the driver
    protected void setDriver(AppiumDriver driver) {
        this.driver.set(driver);
    }

    // Method to get the driver
    public AppiumDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver.get();
    }

    ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();

    public static ExtentReports extentReports;
    public static ExtentTest extentTest;
    public static String screenshotsSubFolderName;

    public String devicename = readconfig.getDeviceName();
    public String path = readconfig.getAppPath();
    public String packagename = readconfig.getAppPackage();
    public String activity = readconfig.getAppActivity();
    public String udid = readconfig.getAppUdid();
    public String url = readconfig.getAppURL();
    public String email = readconfig.getAppUsername();
    public String password = readconfig.getAppPassword();
 

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void initiateExtentReports() {
        extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        ExtentSparkReporter sparkReporter_all = new ExtentSparkReporter("AllTests.html");
        extentReports.attachReporter(sparkReporter_all);

        extentReports.setSystemInfo("OS", System.getProperty("os.name"));
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Java Version", System.getProperty("java.version"));
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Testing Framework", "Cucumber");
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void generateExtentReport() {
        extentReports.flush();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setupTest(Method method) {
        extentTest = extentReports.createTest(method.getName());
    }

    // To attach Screenshot to Extent Report
    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void checkStatus(Method m, ITestResult result) {

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {

            String screenshotPath = null;

            screenshotPath = captureScreenshot(
                    result.getTestContext().getName() + "_" + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + ".jpg",
                    (AndroidDriver)getDriver());

            extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);

            extentTest.fail(result.getThrowable());

        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {

            extentTest.pass(m.getName() + " is passed");
        }

//      extentTest.assignCategory(m.getAnnotation(Test.class).groups());

//      extentTest.assignCategory(m.getAnnotation(Test.class).testName());

    }

    // to capture the screenshot
    public static String captureScreenshot(String fileName, AndroidDriver driver) {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File sourceFile = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File destinationFile = new File("./reports/" + fileName);

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return destinationFile.getAbsolutePath();

    }

    public static String captureScreenShotBase64(AppiumDriver driver2) {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver2;
        return ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
    }


    protected void waitForElementClickability(WebElement element, AppiumDriver driver2) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver2, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }

    protected void waitForSingleElementVisibility(WebElement element, AppiumDriver driver2) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver2, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }

}

App Launch:
public class VisionAppLaunch {

protected AndroidDriver driver;

ReadConfig readconfig = new ReadConfig();


public String devicename = readconfig.getDeviceName();
public String path = readconfig.getAppPath();
public String packagename = readconfig.getAppPackage();
public String activity = readconfig.getAppActivity();
public String udid = readconfig.getAppUdid();
public String url = readconfig.getAppURL();
public String email = readconfig.getAppUsername();
public String password = readconfig.getAppPassword();

public void setupAppLaunch() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "14.0");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, devicename);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, path);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", packagename);
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", activity);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);

        try {
            driver = (new AndroidDriver (new URL(url), capabilities));
            System.out.println("Application launched successfully!");
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Failed to create AndroidDriver. Check the URL and capabilities.");
        }
}

}
TestNG XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Cucumber Test Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Cucumber Tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.TestNGRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>


Cucumber Runner Class:
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features/signup.feature", 
        dryRun = false,
        snippets = CucumberOptions.SnippetType.CAMELCASE,
        glue = { "stepDefinitions" },   
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports.html" }, 
        monochrome = true 
)

public class TestNGRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    
}

Page Object Manager:
public class PageObjectManager {
    
    private LoginPage loginPage;
    private VisionAppLaunch visionAppLaunch;

    public LoginPage getLoginPage(AppiumDriver driver) {
        return (loginPage == null) ? loginPage = new LoginPage((AndroidDriver) driver) : loginPage;
    } 
    
    public VisionAppLaunch getVisionAppLaunch(AppiumDriver driver) {
        return (visionAppLaunch == null) ? visionAppLaunch = new VisionAppLaunch() : visionAppLaunch;
    } 
}

Page class:
public class LoginPage extends VisionBase {

      AppiumDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(AppiumDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Next\"]")
    private WebElement liveClassroomNext;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Next\"]")
    private WebElement performAnalysNext;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Next\"]")
    private WebElement allIndiaPrlimsNext;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Next\"]") 
    private WebElement allIndiaMainsNext;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Continue']")
    private WebElement freeResourcesContinue;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "(//android.widget.ImageView)[11]")
    private WebElement menuAtBottom;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Login\"]")
    private WebElement login;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.EditText[1]")
    private WebElement username;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.EditText[2]")
    private WebElement password;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.View[@content-desc=\"Welcome Back!\"]")
    private WebElement welcome;
    
    public void clickOnNextLiveClassroom11() {
        if (liveClassroomNext != null) {
            System.out.println("Next class button is initialized.");
            waitForElementClickability(liveClassroomNext,driver);
            liveClassroomNext.click();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Next class button is NOT initialized.");
            throw new RuntimeException("Next class button is not initialized.");
        }
    }


    public LoginPage clickOnNextLiveClassroom() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds
        waitForElementClickability(liveClassroomNext,driver);
        liveClassroomNext.click();
        return this;
    }

    public LoginPage clickOnNextLivePerformAnalyst() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds
        waitForElementClickability(performAnalysNext,driver);
        performAnalysNext.click();
        return this;
    }

    public LoginPage clickOnNextAllIndiaPrlims() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds
        waitForElementClickability(allIndiaPrlimsNext,driver);
        allIndiaPrlimsNext.click();
        return this;
    }

    public LoginPage clickOnNextAllIndiaMains() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds
        waitForElementClickability(allIndiaMainsNext,driver);
        allIndiaMainsNext.click();
        return this;
    }

    public LoginPage clickOnContinueFreeResources() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds
        waitForElementClickability(freeResourcesContinue,driver);
        freeResourcesContinue.click();
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isWelcomeDisplayedOnLoginScreen() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for the banner text to be displayed
        waitForSingleElementVisibility(welcome,driver);
        welcome.click();
        return welcome.isDisplayed();
    }

    public LoginPage clickOnMenu() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for the banner text to be displayed
        waitForElementClickability(menuAtBottom,driver);
        menuAtBottom.click();
        String base = captureScreenShotBase64(driver);
        extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base, "Screenshot of login page");
        return this;
    }

    // Entering Email Address in the Login page
    public LoginPage enterUsername(String email) {
        waitForSingleElementVisibility(username,driver);
        username.sendKeys(email);
        String val = username.getAttribute("value");
        extentTest.info("Entered Email  : " + val);
        return this;
    }

    public LoginPage clickOnPasswordField() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for the banner text to be displayed
        waitForElementClickability(password,driver);
        password.click();
        return this;
    }

    // Entering password in the Login page
    public LoginPage enterPassword(String pwd) {
        waitForSingleElementVisibility(password,driver);
        password.sendKeys(pwd);
        String val = password.getAttribute("value");
        extentTest.info("Entered password  : " + val);
        return this;
    }

    public LoginPage touchOnTheScreen() throws InterruptedException {

        // Define the point where you want to touch the screen (modify x and y as
        // needed)
        Point tapPoint = new Point(400, 600);

        // Create an input source for touch actions
        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");

        // Create a loop to tap the screen 5 times
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            // Create a sequence to represent the tap action
            Sequence tapSequence = new Sequence(finger, 1);

            // Move to the tap point
            tapSequence.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(),
                    tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y));

            // Tap down
            tapSequence.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));

            // Tap up (to complete the tap action)
            tapSequence.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));

            // Perform the tap action
            ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).perform(Arrays.asList(tapSequence));

            // Optionally add a small delay between taps
            Thread.sleep(2000); // Adjust the sleep time as needed
        }

        return this;

    }

    public LoginPage clickOnLoginButton() {
        // Wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for the banner text to be displayed
        waitForElementClickability(login,driver);
        login.click();
        String base = captureScreenShotBase64(driver);
        extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base, "Screenshot of login page");
        return this;
    }


Step Definitions:
public class Login extends VisionBase {

    @Given("I launch the app")
    public void iLaunchTheApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        PageObjectManager pom = new PageObjectManager();
        pom.getVisionAppLaunch(getDriver()).setupAppLaunch();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // Click on the "Live Classroom" Next button
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnNextLiveClassroom();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Click on the "Performance Analysis" Next button
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnNextLivePerformAnalyst();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Click on the "All India Prelims" Next button
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnNextAllIndiaPrlims();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Click on the "All India Mains" Next button
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnNextAllIndiaMains();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Click on the "Free Resources" Continue button us
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnContinueFreeResources();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).touchOnTheScreen();

    }

    @When("I click on the login button")
    public void iClickOnTheLoginButton() throws InterruptedException {

        PageObjectManager pom = new PageObjectManager();

        // Click on the "Menu" at bottom
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnMenu(); 

        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnLoginButton();

        Thread.sleep(4000);

    }

    @Then("I should see the login page")
    public void iShouldSeeTheLoginPage() throws InterruptedException {

        PageObjectManager pom = new PageObjectManager();

        // Click on the "Menu" at bottom
        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).enterUsername(email);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnPasswordField();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).enterPassword(password);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).isWelcomeDisplayedOnLoginScreen();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        pom.getLoginPage(getDriver()).clickOnLoginButton();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
}

pom file:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FlutterVisionpp</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlutterVisionApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>7.15.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Extent Reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON Simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

Properties File:
deviceName=Moto g24
appPath=E:\\Eclipse\\FlutterVisionApp\\src\\test\\resources\\apps\\app-release.apk
appPackage=com.com.vision.visionias.app.app
appActivity=com.com.vision.visionias.app.app.MainActivity
udid=ZD222LFXGS

url=http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub

Out put:
    Scenario: Open vision app and click on the login button # src/test/resources/features/signup.feature:3
Application launched successfully!
  Given I launch the app                                # stepDefinitions.Login.iLaunchTheApp()
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.nonNull(Require.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:46)
    at org.basepackage.VisionBase.waitForElementClickability(VisionBase.java:137)
    at org.pageclasspackage.LoginPage.clickOnNextLiveClassroom(LoginPage.java:71)
    at stepDefinitions.Login.iLaunchTheApp(Login.java:23)
    at âœ½.I launch the app(file:///E:/Eclipse/FlutterVisionApp/src/test/resources/features/signup.feature:4)

  When I click on the login button                      # stepDefinitions.Login.iClickOnTheLoginButton()
  Then I should see the login page                      # stepDefinitions.Login.iShouldSeeTheLoginPage()

===============================================
Cucumber Test Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

